# how to position navigation bar on the image instead of behind the image using css3?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

How do I place navigation bar on the image instead of behind the image using CSS3?

Because the navigation bar is appearing behind the image in my code.

Here is my CSS:

```
/*header*/
.header .logo{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
} 

body{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 3px rgba(128,128,128,0.4);
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 22px 6px 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: How about a screen shot of what it does look like, and another of what you want it to look like

Comment: Have you looked at z-index

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods available for doing this.

1. You may use `<div>` tag to set the position of navigation bar and the image.For ex:

   `<div id="img" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:50px;">
      <img src="img.jpg">
   </div>
   <div id="nav" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px;">
     <!-- Navigation bar code here-->
   </div>`

   (Change values accordingly)
2. Use the background-image property for the navigation bar. Set the image as a background of the navigation bar (include navigation bar inside a div tag.)

   `#nav{ background-image: url(img.jpg); }`
3. Use z-index

   `#nav{
   z-index:100;
   }`